Is the function differentiable?
Consider the function  $f(x,y)=xy^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(x,y)=0$ for $x=0$. Is the function differentiable at $(0,0)$? I proved it is continuous. I calculated the partial derivatives when $x$ is not zero. Now procceding with the definition seems hard also I couldn't  calculate the limit of the partial derivative with respect to $x$ at $(0,0)$.
$$f_x=y^2(\sin\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}\cos\frac{1}{x})\quad {\rm and}\quad f_y=2yx\sin\frac{1}{x}$$
Question: Since f is zero at that point can I say the partial derivatives at that point exist and are zero? Then find the limit of the partial derivative I calculated away from my point and check if it is also zero( which I cant find the limit of the first). If the limits disagree the partial derivatives are not continuous. But then again that doesn't solve if its differentiable or not. It might be differentiable without having partial derivatives continuous.

Use the definition and the fact that $x^2+y^2\geq 2xy$.

@JulioPuerta for which linear transformation? i cant just take the difference like in one dimension.

The partials at the origin are trivially $0$ by definition. Then, we can apply the above bound (see José Carlos Santos answer)

According to the definition of partial derivatives,
$$f_{x}(0,0)=\lim _{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0+\Delta x, 0)-f(0,0)}{\Delta x}=\lim _{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{0-0}{\Delta x}=0.$$
Similarly, it can be concluded that $f_{y}(0,0)=0$. Finally, according to the definition of differentiability, we have
$$\lim_{(\Delta x,\Delta y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{\Delta f-f_{x}(0,0)\Delta x-f_{y}(0,0)\Delta y}{\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}}=\lim_{(\Delta x,\Delta y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{\Delta x(\Delta y)^2}{\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}}\sin\frac1{\Delta x}=0.$$
Therefore the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Thanks  i didnt think i can just say the linear aproximation is zero. Also are the partial derivatives continuous at (0,0) .Does the limit of the partial derivative i calculated exist at (0,0)??. I tried factoring y^2 but still..

When $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, the limit of $f_x$ does not exist, so $f_x$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$. But $f_y$ is continuous at $(0,0)$

how did you find it does not exist thats where im stuck . I figured it might not cause of the trigs with 1/x.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f_x(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}y^2(\sin\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}\cos(\frac{1}{x}))$$
If we let $(x, y)\to(0,0)$ in the way $y=\sqrt x$, then we have
$$\lim_{x\to0}(\sqrt x)^2(\sin\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}\cos(\frac{1}{x}))=\lim_{x\to0}(x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x})=\text{non-existent}$$

For each $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, you have$$\sqrt2\lvert xy\rvert\leqslant\sqrt{x^2+y^2},$$and therefore$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\left| xy^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\right|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\overbrace{\frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}^{\phantom{1/\sqrt2}\leqslant1/\sqrt2}|y|\overbrace{\left|\sin\left(\frac1x\right)\right|}^{\phantom{1}\leqslant1}=0.$$So, $f'(0,0)$ is the null function.

Considering that both partial derivatives are zero at point $(0,0)$, you need to analyse the limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0}\dfrac{x y^2 \sin(1/x)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$.
Now, since
$$
\left|\dfrac{x y^2 \sin(1/x)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right|\leq |x| \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\to 0 \quad ((x,y)\to (0,0))
$$
the function is indeed differentiable at $(0,0)$.
